# How do you distinguish a directory, and it's contents in linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, cp

Let's say you have this directory tree

```
parent
   -----child1
           -----file0 
           -----grandchild1
                      -----file1
                      -----file2 
           -----grandchild2
                      -----file3
   -----child2
```

Now there are two things I need to learn how to do

1. Copy the folder child1 into child2, so that there will be a parent/child2/child1/grancdhild1/file1
2. Copy the contents of folder child1 to child2, so there will parent/child2/grancdhild1/file1

Notice the second one does not have a "child1", in the first one we are copying a folder into a new folder, in the second one we are copying the contents of a folder to another folder.

If it matters, lets say your current location is parent.

My main challenge here is to copy everything (sub directories, hidden files etc..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rsync to the rescue! :-)

Watch that slash character (or its absence) at the end of the 'child1' parameter. That is the only difference. The commands are executed in `parent`.

`$ rsync -a child1 child2/`

Result:

```
├── child1
│   ├── file0
│   ├── grandchild1
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   └── file2
│   └── grandchild2
│       └── file3
└── child2
    └── child1
        ├── file0
        ├── grandchild1
        │   ├── file1
        │   └── file2
        └── grandchild2
            └── file3
```

`$ rsync -a child1/ child2/`

Result:

```
├── child1
│   ├── file0
│   ├── grandchild1
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   └── file2
│   └── grandchild2
│       └── file3
└── child2
    ├── file0
    ├── grandchild1
    │   ├── file1
    │   └── file2
    └── grandchild2
        └── file3
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `parent` is your working direcotry

To do 1: `cp -r child1 child2`

To do 2: `cp -r child1/* child2`

There are different implementations of `cp` in *nix world but `-r` switch should work. Check your documentation for details. Also take a look at `-a` switch in GNU `cp`.

Comment: Note that shell globbing (here, the '*') usually won't match anything starting with a period ('.').

Comment: Stupid dotfiles.

Comment: So in linux, * marches directories (unlike MS DOS), but not hidden files correct?

Comment: It wouldn't be right to say "in linux" because "\*" symbol expansion depends on specific shell. For specific details about "\*" meaning in bash I must point you to bash documentation section "Pathname Extension", part about environmental variable "GLOBIGNORE" and description of "dotglob" option (they say a bit about "\*" expanding to file names starting with dot). Be advised: other shells may behave differently in that matter.

Comment: @Eroen is right - * doesn't match dot files. But there's another way to copy everything (including dot files!) from `child1` to `child2`. Just replace that * with a . (dot), as in: `cp -r child1/. child2`

Answer (score 0):

To copy child1, you would do `cp child1 child2/child1`. To copy the contents of child1, you would do `cp child1/* child2/*`.

Comment: Aaand, that probably just got flagged by the FBI :P

Comment: Does that copy the directories inside child1?

Comment: I believe it will. I'm at work right now, and don't have access to any Linux systems. You may have to add the -r tag for that.

Comment: The -r option is needed for cp, not for mv. Although, you'd probably be better of with "cp child1 child2/"

Comment: @Eroen Right, but he said he wanted to copy it, not move it.